# Enabling and disabling title bar in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest

I want to enable and disable the title bar based on the entry point for the activity. How can i do it(may it be in xml or in code)?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this.. its a hack..

```
titleView = getWindow().findViewById(android.R.id.title);
    if (titleView != null) {
        ViewParent parent = titleView.getParent();
        if (parent != null && (parent instanceof View)) {
         View parentView = (View)parent;
         parentView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

you can hide the title bar like this way

```
//Remove title bar
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

//Remove notification bar
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

or modify in xml file like this way

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
```

or using style with xml file like this way

```
<style name="generalnotitle" parent="general">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I want the title bar to be displayed in the activity only in some cases. So if i set the NoTitleBar theme, the title bar is totally removed from the activity in all cases. But i want to enable the title bar in some cases and disable in some cases. If i try to set the above theme and enable it in code using **requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE)**, it throws an exception **You cannot combine custom titles with other title features**.

Comment: For the individual activities that need the title bar just give them there own theme in the manifest file.

Comment: This works fine,but was trying to do without new styles. Styles give me the creeps... :)